# Scala Thunk or Code Block

Tags: scala

I read about the tricky Scala code block in [SCALA GOTCHA: BLOCKS AND FUNCTIONS](http://downgra.de/2010/08/05/scala_gotcha_blocks_and_functions/) and [Alvin](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/anonymous-classes-in-scala-examples)'s blog. This is a follow up to Alvin's example where he used a generic function, `f: A=> B` for code block parameter instead of `() => A` or `=> A`.

I changed the code to return an `Int` instead of a `String`, please refer to `#1`,

```
case class Foo[A, B](f: A => B) {
    println(f)
    def print1 { println("1") }
    }

    object AnonymousClassTest1 extends App {

    val f1 = Foo {
        println("hello from the `f1` instance")
        // "this is the result of the block of code" // #1
        123
    }
        f1.print1
    }
```

This code compiled with an error,

```
Example.scala:5: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(123)
 required: ? => ?
           123
           ^
one error found
```

Given that *f* is a generic function that takes anything and returns anything. Why there is a compilation error? And why it can accept String but not Int? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break down explanation into two parts:
Scala allows for replacing argument list accepting excactly one argument with block:

```
def foo(arg: Int) = arg + 42
foo(42) == foo { 42 }
```

So for your code the following should be true

```
val f1 = Foo {
myGreatCode
}
val f2 = Foo(myGreateCode)
f1 == f2
```

Value (which implies Type) "returned" from the block is the last expression in the latter, so in your case:

```
val f1 = Foo {
    println("hello from the `f1` instance")
    // "this is the result of the block of code" // #1
    123
}
f1 == Foo(123) // println is executed before creating Foo
```

I hope it explains why you are getting compilation error. For your need scala provides special syntax allowing for definition of a function in a block:

```
val f2 = Foo { x: String =>
  x.toInt
} // Foo[String, Int]
```

Edit:

Following discussion in the comments i found explanaition why `Foo("123")` compiles. If someone inspects the code, he/she will find out that generic arguments for the following instance are: `Foo[Int, Char]`.
This happens because of the following:

1. Compilers expects argument of Foo.apply to be a function
2. Passed value is not a function so compiler looks for implicit conversion to one.
3. It finds: `implicit def wrapString(s: String): WrappedString = if (s ne null) new WrappedString(s) else null` and `WrappedString` extends `IndexedSeq[Char]` which in turn extends `Int => Char`

Comment: Foo(123) failed to compile but Foo("123") compiled. I don't think println was the cause if  I understand from you correctly

Comment: Do you mean that your class Foo with argument "123" compiled?

Comment: Yes. It compiled with "123". Probably I should include that in my question

Comment: that trail of implicitness is crazy but good catch i guess... scary what implicit conversions can dig up when generics are involved